# Why are *accept* and *except* commonly misspelled as each other? Are they homophones?

Tags: orthography, dialects, homophones

Why are *accept* and *except* commonly confused for each other when writing? This is unlike most cases, where misspellings come from homophones.

In my idiolect at least, *accept* is /ək.'sɛpt/, and *except* is /ɪk.'sɛpt/. They are not homophonic, and are about as close as *butter* and *bitter*. However, this pair seems strangely prone to misspelling all over the place. Are these words homophonic in standard English? I am technically not a native speaker (picked up English while really young), live in Canada, and people tend to comment me having a weird accent...

Comment: I am AmE, and they sound different to me as well, but not as dramatically as butter/bitter. I wouldn't confuse them on hearing them. Unlike you, I have not seen these two confused in writing much.

Comment: Rather than phonetic similarity (which does make matters worse), it is more likely a confusion over which word has which meaning that is responsible here. There may be more such non-homophonic pairs/groups as well that tend to confuse.

Comment: I'd throw in _affect_ and _effect_ as oft-confused verbs :)

Comment: @oerkelens and nouns.

Comment: And nouns, indeed :)

Comment: @oerkelens this is almost definitely my idiosyncratic pronunciation, but for me *affect* and *effect* are sometimes homophonous, but sometimes not, since I randomly switch between /i:.'fekt/ and /ə.'fekt/ for *effect*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phonetic difference is in an unstressed syllable, and English in general tends to reduce unstressed syllables toward the mid-central [schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) sound. In some accents these words are homophones. In others, *except* is pronounced with a near-close, near-front /ɪ/ or an open-mid front /ɛ/, but in casual or rapid speech, they may be difficult or impossible to distinguish from a mid-central /ə/.

Comment: True, but learners tend to get confused with other pairs as well. See my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris Agreed, you don't need to have a homophone to confuse words, although it helps. And these words are very close, much closer than bitter and butter.

Answer (score 0):

To accept is from Latin accipere meaning basically to take and to except from Latin excipere meaning to exclude. Though they sound almost similar, the context of their use is different. You can accept a proposition and you can except certain people from a tax. So you hear from context and the verb construction what is what.